# English or Hindi translation of Vyasa Smriti

Tags: vyasa, smriti, resource

Is there any site or way to get a pdf or epub of Hindi/English translation of Vyasa Smriti?
I have searched many sites and couldn't find it.
Please if someone has it kindly provide a link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Hindi translation will work for you, you can download it from [here](https://ia800306.us.archive.org/18/items/AshtadashSmriti/ashtadash_smriti.pdf).

The PDF not only has Vyasa Smriti but it has got 18 Smritis in all (Sanskrit verses+Hindi translation).

[image]

From the image given above, you can check which of the Smritis it has. It has Smritis like Atri, Vishnu, Vashishta, Vyasa, Brihaspati, Katyayana, etc. The name of the book is Aastadashasmriti (18 Smritis)

Answer (score 1):

M. N. Dutt's English translation of Vyāsa Smṛti a.k.a Vyāsa Saṃhitā can be found on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/vyasa-smriti-m-n-dutt):

https://archive.org/details/vyasa-smriti-m-n-dutt

https://archive.org/download/vyasa-smriti-m-n-dutt/Vyasa%20Smriti%20-%20M%20N%20Dutt.pdf (PDF)