# Where can I get Daksha smriti in English or Hindi translation?

Tags: translation-request, smriti

Daksha smriti is a part of 18 major smritis and an English or Hindi version is not available on internet other than a google book which costs too much.

Does anyone has daksha smriti in Englsih translated version?

Comment: You can get Daksha Smriti (Sanskrit verses+Hindi translation) from the book I shared in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34651/4732

Comment: @Rickross ,ty i only made account to get this book but couldnt coment on your answer where you cited daksha smriti as source (50 reputations limit), ty for this :-). so happy

Comment: No problem :) I am happy to know that I was able to help. And welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Daksha Smriti can be found in [this link of Archive](https://archive.org/details/AshtadashSmriti/page/n370/mode/1up).

Comment: YDS Hi I hope you are doing good in these troubled times. Its been a long time since I have interacted with you.

Comment: @Rickross yeah, things r ok ok at my side..thank you..I hope u r also doing good..

Comment: Ok good .. Yeah I am too fine .. @YDS